# How do I print a list of numbers vertically?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve an exercise. I should write a function that takes a list of integers, converts it to a string of numbers displayed vertically.

```
mylist = [5,69,2090]
```

the function should return/print the following string:

```
    2
    0
  6 9
5 9 0
```

I tried to solve it with the following code, but it doesn't help me

```
def printstring(mylist):
    h = len(mylist)//3
    for i in range(h):
        print(mylist[i],mylist[h+i],l[h+i+1])
```

Comment: Can you show the desired output for some more inputs...?

Comment: I'm sorry, i'll change it

Comment: @Yatin it's not a reserved keyword but a builtin name. A reserved keyword is something like `if`, `def`, `return` etc. and you can't even assign something to them. However, shadowing a builtin name is a bad thing because you can no longer use that builtin function.

Answer (score 4):

```
lst = [5,69,2090]

n = max(len(str(i)) for i in lst)
for i in zip(*['{:>{n}}'.format(i, n=n) for i in lst]):
    print(' '.join(i))
```

Prints:

```
    2
    0
  6 9
5 9 0
```

---

For `lst = [1,123,12,12345,1234]`:

```
      1  
      2 1
  1   3 2
  2 1 4 3
1 3 2 5 4
```

Comment: I think you could also change `len(str(max(lst, key=lambda k: len(str(k)))))` to `max((len(str(k)) for k in lst))`

Comment: why not: n = len(str(max(lst)))

Comment: Good idea but maybe negative numbers breaks that. I sort of like the idea of stringifying it anyway so it works with non-numeric input.

Comment: @AndrejKesely can you explain the `['{:>{n}}'.format(i, n=n) for i in lst]` part please... in perticular `{:>{n}}` ...

Comment: @Yatin `{:>{n}}` will align the string to `n` characters to the right (and pad the rest with spaces). More info here: https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align

Comment: @Asocia that is not true, because the list contains integers, meaning that max returns the biggest int, after that it is converted to strin and only then you use len().

Comment: @Andreas Oh, you are correct. I was thinking them as strings because I convert them to strings in my answer :D

Comment: @Asocia If there's negative integer, the `-` sign will not align correctly.

Answer (score 4):

First convert your list items to a string then find the maximum length. Pad your strings to fit that length and print them:

```
lst = [5, 69, 2090]
lst = list(map(str, lst))
max_lenght = max(map(len, lst))
padded_lst = [item.rjust(max_lenght, " ") for item in lst]
for row in zip(*padded_lst):
    print(" ".join(row))
```

```
    2
    0
  6 9
5 9 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd apply a few steps here. First, determine the maximum length of digits for each number by converting them to strings. Secondly, left pad each number string to that length using `rjust`. Finally, rotate the matrix 90 degrees using the classic `zip(*m)` trick and join it all back into a printable square.

```
>>> lst = [5,69,2090]
>>> size = max(map(len, map(str, lst)))
>>> m = [str(x).rjust(size, " ") for x in lst]
>>> print("\n".join([" ".join(x) for x in zip(*m)]))
    2
    0
  6 9
5 9 0
```

Answer (score 1):

A not so much readable two liner

```
sl = ['{:>{}d}'.format(s, len(str(max(mylist)))) for s in mylist]
print('\n'.join(' '.join(s) for s in zip(*sl)))
```